# Why does app crash when page starts to load due to useEffect hook with firebase upload in React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying to upload a photo to firebase storage in my post screen/page.  I thought I was supposed to use an useEffect hook when calling api's so I did that and put in a dependency array for the two states that had to change for rerender.  When I delete the useEffect and just have the uploadImage function and then I run the uploadImage function in the imagePicker function after confirming the event wasn't cancelled, it works but I can't seem to get the folder/imagename right.  I can only call it something and then it continues to overwrite.

the workflow should be render the two buttons on screen, when the photo picker button is pressed, run the chooseFromLibrary function which will set the state for imageFilename and imageSelected(uri).  That should tell the dependency array to run the effect of calling the uploadImage function with the variables for imageSelected and imageFilename.  I want the ref in the uploadImage function to create/put in the folder for user.username (this is from context) and then the image name to be be imageFilename but it doesn't seem to be working.

What am I doing wrong?

```
const [user] = useContext(UserContext);
const [imageSelected, setImageSelected] = useState("");
const [imageFilename, setImageFilename] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {
    uploadImage(imageSelected, imageFilename)
      .then(() => {
        Alert.alert("Success");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        Alert.alert(error);
      });
  }, [imageFilename, imageSelected]);

const uploadImage = async (uri, name) => {
    const response = await fetch(uri);
    const blob = await response.blob();
    var ref = firebase
      .storage()
      .ref()
      .child(`${user.username}` + name);
    return ref.put(blob);
  };

const chooseFromLibrary = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });
    if (!result.cancelled) {
      let fileArray = result.uri.split("/");
      let name = fileArray.pop();
      setImageFilename(name);
      setImageSelected(result.uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check how many times you call uploadImage ? (console.log or someting). You don't have AboardControler

Answer (score 0):

I had to run an if statement returning the effect if an image hadn't been selected yet.

```
if (!imageSelected) {
      return;
    }
```